# copying a value type that has reference type as a member

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

If I copy a Value Type that has a Reference Type member (string in my case), CLR does a shallow copy ([book](http://www.apress.com/9781430242338)). So I wrote a small program just to experiment but cannot get the expected result. I am sure I am missing some detail here.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Example");
        //first example
        Point p1 = new Point();
        p1.Name = "firstPoint";
        p1.X = 10;
        p1.Y = 20;

        Point p2 = p1;

        p2.Name = "secondPoint";
        p2.X = 40;
        p2.Y = 50;

        p1.Print(); //Prints - Name: firstPoint, X:10, Y:20
                    //Expected - Name: secondPoint, X:10, Y:20
        p2.Print(); //Prints - Name: secondPoint, X:40, Y:50

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public struct Point
{
    public string Name;
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, X: {1}, Y: {2}", this.Name.ToString(), this.X, this.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am expecting p1.Print() to output 'Name: secondPoint, X:40, Y: 50' as Name is reference type and got modified by p2.

Comment: @VaibhavGathibandhe You are changing the reference itself so old object p1 would stick to old reference and new reference would get assigned to p2 object.

Comment: @Jenish... thanks, makes perfect sense.

Comment: @VaibhavGathibandhe You may refer my updated answer it has attached example as well.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I was thinking the old object (that p1.Name references to) is being replaced by new one. Instead, a new string is created and its reference is placed in p2.Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed your whole reference type so it behaved like that instead of that you can try changing member of that reference type in order to verify and play around it.

see below code for your reference:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Example");
        //first example
        Point p1 = new Point();
        p1.store = new SomeClass();
        p1.store.Name = "Jenish";
        p1.Name = "firstPoint";
        p1.X = 10;
        p1.Y = 20;

        Point p2 = p1;

        p2.Name = "secondPoint";
        p2.store.Name = "Jenish2";
        p2.X = 40;
        p2.Y = 50;

        p1.Print(); //Prints - Name: firstPoint, X:10, Y:20
        p2.Print(); //Prints - Name: secondPoint, X:40, Y:50

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public struct Point
{
    
    public string Name;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public SomeClass store;

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, X: {1}, Y: {2}, Name: {3}", this.Name.ToString(), this.X, this.Y, this.store.Name);
    }
}

public class SomeClass{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

**output**

> First Example
>
> Name: firstPoint, X: 10, Y: 20, Name: Jenish2
>
> Name: secondPoint, X: 40, Y: 50, Name: Jenish2

Here is [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CXivhU) for you.

Below example demonstrate the case what happens when you changes whole reference type.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Example");
        //first example
        Point p1 = new Point();
        p1.store = new SomeClass();
        p1.store.Name = "Jenish";
        p1.Name = "firstPoint";
        p1.X = 10;
        p1.Y = 20;

        Point p2 = p1;

        p2.Name = "secondPoint";
        p2.store = new SomeClass();
        p2.store.Name = "Jenish2";
        p2.X = 40;
        p2.Y = 50;

        p1.Print(); //Prints - Name: firstPoint, X:10, Y:20
        p2.Print(); //Prints - Name: secondPoint, X:40, Y:50

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public struct Point
{
    
    public string Name;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public SomeClass store;

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, X: {1}, Y: {2}, Name: {3}", this.Name.ToString(), this.X, this.Y, this.store.Name);
    }
}

public class SomeClass{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

**Note**: name is different in both the object.

Here is [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XSqzOt) for the second example.

Comment: There is nothing special about `string` in sample provided by OP. Setting `p2.store`  to new instance of `SomeClass` would behave the same way as setting `p2.Name` to new instance of the string.